# With one button I want to call a php function as well as a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a file, where i use a button, called MP4 Quality, When i click on that button, it opens a pop-up and ask for another button to press, to download the video, There is javascript with first button, and when it clicks, open the pop-up and give the second button, from where PHP is used, now i want it to download on single click,

Following is the code for first button...

```
<button id="videoDownloadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onClick="downloadVideo();">MP4 Quality</button>
```

and when it click, the following javascript code will run

```
function downloadVideo() {
    var videoID = player.getVideoData()['video_id']
    document.getElementById("downloadFormatList").innerHTML="Please wait. Processing...";
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("downloadFormatList").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
    }
  }

  //keyword = keyword.replace(/ /g, '%2B');
    xmlhttp3.open("GET","TMB/download.php?videoid="+videoID,true);
  xmlhttp3.send();

}
```

and after that PHP code will run, PHP code is this...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['videoid'])) {
$my_id = $_REQUEST['videoid'];

if(strpos($my_id,"https://youtu.be/") !== false)
{
    $my_id = str_replace("https://youtu.be/","",$my_id);
}
}


<?php

//$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.     $my_id;
$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=' . $my_id . '&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US'; //video details fix *1
$my_video_info = curlGet($my_video_info);
/* TODO: Check return from curl for status code */
$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
parse_str($my_video_info);
?>



<?php
$my_title     = $title;
$cleanedtitle = clean($title);
if (isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
/* Now get the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, and explode on comma */
$my_formats_array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
if ($debug) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($my_formats_array);
    echo '</pre>';
}
} else {
echo '<p>No encoded format stream found.</p>';
echo '<p>Here is what we got from YouTube:</p>';
echo $my_video_info;
}
if (count($my_formats_array) == 0) {
echo '<p>No format stream map found - was the video id correct?</p>';
exit;
}
/* create an array of available download formats */
$avail_formats[] = '';
$i               = 0;
$ipbits          = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
$expire          = time();
foreach ($my_formats_array as $format) {
parse_str($format);
$avail_formats[$i]['itag']    = $itag;
$avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
$type                         = explode(';', $type);
$avail_formats[$i]['type']    = $type[0];
$avail_formats[$i]['url']     = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
parse_str(urldecode($url));
$avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
$avail_formats[$i]['ipbits']  = $ipbits;
$avail_formats[$i]['ip']      = $ip;
$i++;
}


echo '<div class="format_list">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<table>';

 /* now that we have the array, print the options */
 for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
if ($config['VideoLinkMode'] == 'direct' || $config['VideoLinkMode'] == 'both')
?> <tr><td><?php
echo $avail_formats[$i]['type'];
?></td>

    <td><small>(<?php
   echo $avail_formats[$i]['quality'];
 ?>)</small> </td>
    <td><small><span class="size"><?php
   echo formatBytes(get_size($avail_formats[$i]['url']));
?></span></small>
    </td>

    <td><a href="<?php
echo $avail_formats[$i]['url'];
?> '&title='<?php
echo $cleanedtitle;
?>'" class="downloadButton">Record Video</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

after the click on first button, this button will appear,

```
<a href="<?php echo $avail_formats[$i]['url']; ?> '&title='<?php echo $cleanedtitle; ?>'" class="downloadButton">Record Video</a>
```

Now i want it on single click, how can i do...??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the bottom of your pop-up page:

```
<script>
    window.location = '<?php echo $avail_formats[$i]['url']; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your php code, the "second button" term is not correct.
You might have a count of second buttons which have different quality.

This is why the php code and second click exist.

If you want to download your video immediately, replace your foreach loop in php code

```
foreach ($my_formats_array as $format) {


  parse_str($format);
    $avail_formats[$i]['itag']    = $itag;
    $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
    $type                         = explode(';', $type);
    $avail_formats[$i]['type']    = $type[0];
    $avail_formats[$i]['url']     = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
    parse_str(urldecode($url));
    $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
    $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits']  = $ipbits;
    $avail_formats[$i]['ip']      = $ip;
    $i++;
}
```

on the

```
    if (isset($my_formats_array[0])) {
          parse_str($my_formats_array[0]);
          header("Location: " . urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig);
          die();
    }
```

And get rid of other unnecessary things

Comment: yeah, you are right, i don't need that thing, but how can i download that format, without clicking the second button, When i place your code instead of that code, and run it, it is continuously keep on processing and automatically timeout, and give nothing.

Comment: there are could be errors in the code, it has to be debugged